# When playing Edgar Markov, what is the definition of a "Vampire spell"?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I'm quite new to MtG, so this may be a noob question. I play EDH/Commander with [Edgar Markov](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bEdgar%20Markov%5d) as my commander. His text reads "*Eminence* - Whenever you cast another Vampire spell, if Edgar Markov is in the command zone or on the battlefield, create a 1/1 black Vampire creature token".

Obviously this will trigger for vampire *creature* spells ("[Vampire Cutthroat](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bVampire%20Cutthroat%5d)", "["Pulse Tracker"](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5b%22Pulse%20Tracker%22%5d), "[Crypt Ghast](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCrypt%20Ghast%5d)" etc), but will it trigger for other spells? For instance, are instants like "[Vampire's Zeal](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bVampire%27s%5d%2b%5bZeal%5d)" and "["Vampire's Bite"](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5b%22Vampire%27s%5d%2b%5bBite%22%5d) or enchantments like "[Mark of the Vampire](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMark%20of%20the%20Vampire%5d)" considered "Vampire spells"?

I have a hunch that cards that contain the word "Vampire" in their *name* or *type line* are concidered vampire spells, but that cards with the word in their *text box* are not. Is this correct?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A Vampire spell (for the purpose of Edgar Markov) is a spell which has the Vampire *(sub)type*; its *name* doesn't matter. You can find the type(s) in the bar between the picture and the rules text. Vampire Cutthroat is a "Creature - Vampire Rogue", so it counts; Mark of the Vampire is an "Enchantment - Aura", so it doesn't count.

There are no non-creature spells which *explicitly* have the Vampire subtype, as [this Gatherer search shows](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&subtype=+%5B%22Vampire%22%5D&type=+!%5B%22Creature%22%5D). There *are* non-creature spells which have *all* creature types thanks to the Changeling ability, such as [Crib Swap](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCrib%20Swap%5d); [this search lists all 6 of them](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&text=+[Changeling]&type=+![Creature]).

Comment: All current Vampire spells are creatures, [see here](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&subtype=+[%22Vampire%22]&type=+![%22Creature%22])

Comment: @Hackworth. [These 6 instants](https://scryfall.com/search?as=grid&order=name&q=oracle%3AChangeling+type%3Atribal) are vampires.

Comment: Maybe not needed for a new player, note that as "Vampire" is a *creature* subtype, it can normally only apply to creatures. But "Tribal" is a special subtype that allows non-creatures to have creature subtypes.

Comment: Nitpick: Tribal is a type, it pumps Tarmogoyf.

Comment: Tribal is weird in a lot of ways (which is why it isn't printed anymore).  It is technically a type (which only matters for Tarmogoyf, and maybe a few other cards), but it acts like a supertype.

Comment: @Arcainst Lupus I remember a competitive magic player once told me in 2007 that he would not have made it to National that year if the Merfolk mill decks pilots that he faced in the first two rounds of regionals realised they could tap there Merfolk enchantment to Drowner of Secrets ability.